# How to make my code more simplified?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, function

Can anyone help me to simplified my code..i made 5 different function with the same function the only difference is that the name inside the list that will display information.

Just give me an idea how to make it short.

**My Code:**

```
def country():
   cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
   cur.callproc('spGetAllCountry')
   data = cur.fetchall()

   country_list=[];
   for country in data:
       i = {
        'Name' : country[2],
        'Code' : country[0],
        'Description' : country[1]
        }
       country_list.append(i)

   return jsonify(country_list)

def currency():
   cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
   cur.callproc('spGetAllCurrency')
   data = cur.fetchall()

   currency_list=[];
   for currency in data:
      i = {
        'Name' : currency[2],
        'Code' : currency[0],
        'Description' : currency[1]
        }
      currency_list.append(i)

   return jsonify(currency_list)

def paymentbrand():
   cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
   cur.callproc('spGetPaymentbrand')
   data = cur.fetchall()

   paymentbrand_list=[];
   for paymentbrand in data:
      i = {
        'Name' : paymentbrand[2],
        'Code' : paymentbrand[0],
        'Description' : paymentbrand[1],
                    'Payment Code' : paymentbrand[3]
        }
      paymentbrand_list.append(i)

   return jsonify(paymentbrand_list)

def paymentmode():
   cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
   cur.callproc('spGetPaymentmode')
   data = cur.fetchall()

   paymentmode_list=[];
   for paymentmode in data:
       i = {
        'Name' : paymentmode[2],
        'Code' : paymentmode[0],
        'Description' : paymentmode[1]
        }
       paymentmode_list.append(i)

   return jsonify(paymentmode_list)
```

Comment: Why the Java tag?

Comment: You should post this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you fix your indentation?

Comment: Done Editing @Nuageux

Comment: @RichardTao, still some errors (return outside of def). You should also consider Steve Smith comment.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def get_data(func_name, value_idx_map):
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.callproc(func_name)
    dataArr = cur.fetchall()

    res=[]
    for item in dataArr:
        v = { key: item[idx] for key, idx in value_idx_map.items()}
        res.append(v)
    return pprint.pprint(res)

common_idx = {'Name': 2, 'Code': 0, 'Description': 1}

get_data('spGetAllCountry', common_idx)
get_data('spGetAllCurrency', common_idx)
get_data('spGetPaymentmode', common_idx)

common_idx['Payment Code'] = 3
get_data('spGetPaymentbrand', common_idx)
```

Comment: Thanks Bro :) ill try this.